# Line Breaks in showing formula field in VF page

Tags: visualforce, line-break

I've a formula field like this :

```
Address__c & BR() + City__c & ',' & text(State__c) & BR() & Zip_Code__c
```

This is showing complete mailing address, separated by line breaks using BR() function

This works fine in reports But when it try to display this field in VF page using OutputText tag, 
This come up like this :

[image]

what can I do avoid this ?

Answer (score 1):

By default, the `apex:outputText` component escapes special HTML characters to prevent injection attacks.  In this case, it's catching the HTML line breaks generated by the `BR()` function.  You can override this behaviour by setting the attribute `escape="false"` on the tag.  Alternately, if you're just displaying a formula field, you might want to use the `apex:outputField` component instead, although this will also generate a field label.

Details on the two components can be found here:

[apex:outputText](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputText.htm)

[apex:outputField](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputField.htm)